# Multiple low level function calls using inline assembly in a smart contract not working

Tags: solidity, assembly

I'm trying to low-level call two separate contracts (B and C, with the same function signature) using inline assembly from my own contract (A) within the same function. The call to B modifies some external state which affects whether the call to C is successful.

Without inline-assembly the low-level calls to B and C work fine. If I use inline-assembly for the call to B but keep the low-level call to C non-inline-assembly, the transaction also works as expected. But if I use inline-assembly for both low-level calls to B and C, the call to C fails with a revert within C's function that I'm calling.

Here is a code example of what I'm trying to do:

```
Contract A {

 function foo(address addressB, address addressC, ...){

  assembly {
      let x := mload(0x40)
      mstore(x, sig)
      mstore(add(x, 0x04), fooB)
      mstore(add(x, 0x24), barB)
      mstore(add(x, 0x44), bazB)
      mstore(add(x, 0x64), quxB)
      mstore(0x40, add(x, 0x84))

      pop(call(gas(), addressB, 0, x, 0x84, 0, 0))
      mstore(0x40, add(x, 0x84))
    }

  assembly {
      let x := mload(0x40)
      mstore(x, sig)
      mstore(add(x, 0x04), fooC)
      mstore(add(x, 0x24), barC)
      mstore(add(x, 0x44), bazC)
      mstore(add(x, 0x64), quxC)
      mstore(0x40, add(x, 0x84))

      pop(call(gas(), addressC, 0, x, 0x84, 0, 0))
      mstore(0x40, add(x, 0x84))
    }
}

}
```

Where addressB is the address of contract B etc. Foo, bar, baz, qux are all passed in the foo function.

From all the debugging I've done, it seems like only one assembly block can work but not two. (If I comment out the first block, I can make the second block run fine). So it seems like they're interfering with each other in some way. But I don't see how because I'm resetting the free memory pointer before the second call. Are two low-level inline assembly calls with the same signature not allowed for some reason?

Many thanks for your help.